# UIImagePickerController and blank ImageView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a problem which is really strange : I have a TableViewController with 2 pictures and 2 buttons. The user could change the picture with the button.

The problem is when the user click on the button, the UIActionSheet opens, the user chooses the "Photo from library" and then select a photo in the library. The UIActionSheet closes but there is no picture in my ImageView... It's still blank... (My ImageView are linked to @ property).

Here is my code :

.H file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EditUserTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *avatar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *coverPhoto;

- (IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender;

@end
```

.M file :

```
#import "EditUserTableViewController.h"

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, THPhotoType)
{
    THPhotoTypeCoverPhoto = 10,
    THPhotoTypeAvatarPhoto = 20
};

@interface EditUserTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) THPhotoType selectedPhotoType;

@end

@implementation EditUserTableViewController

@synthesize coverPhoto, avatar;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
} 

- (IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *button = sender;
        _selectedPhotoType = button.tag;
    }
    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Picture" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"From Library", @"From Camera", nil];
    [sheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex < 2) {
        UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceType type;

        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                type = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                break;
            case 1:
                type = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        imagePicker.sourceType = type;
        imagePicker.delegate = self;

        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{ }];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    switch (_selectedPhotoType) {
        case THPhotoTypeCoverPhoto:
            coverPhoto.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            break;
        case THPhotoTypeAvatarPhoto:
            avatar.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ }];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem in setting image to your image view.Try this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    switch (_selectedPhotoType) {
        case THPhotoTypeCoverPhoto:
          self.coverPhoto.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            break;
        case THPhotoTypeAvatarPhoto:
           self.avatar.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ }];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm a "%^&*&^"...

It was a problem of tag for my buttons...

Problem is solved !